# Unable to update the state of a react component

Tags: reactjs, components, react-hooks

I am a novice full stack developer working on a basic shopping cart front-end task.

My cartItems array which is is a part of the state is not updating when I click on addtoCart. The addtoCart function is being called but, the update is not happening. No errors are being shown either

MY shopping cart component is

```
export default class Cart extends Component {
    render() {
        const {cartItems} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                {cartItems.length === 0 ? ( 
                    <div className='cart cart-header'>Cart is empty</div>
                    ) : (
                    <div className='cart cart-header'>You have {cartItems.length} items in yout cart{" "}</div>
                    )
                }
</div>
```

My code to add the item to cart in App js is :

```
addToCart = (product) => {
    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
    console.log(cartItems); 
    let alreadyInCart = false;
    cartItems.forEach((item) => {
      if(item._id === product._id) { 
      item.count++;
      alreadyInCart=true;
    }
    if(!alreadyInCart) {
      cartItems.push({...product, count:1});
    }
  })
    this.setState({cartItems});
    console.log(this.state.cartItems)
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

- `item.count++;` is a state mutation
- You can't console log state right after a state update and expect it to log the the state from the *next* render cycle.

## Solution

- Search the array first to detect if the cart already contains item.
- Use a functional state update.
- Shallow copy the array ***and*** individual elements you update
- Log state in a lifecycle function, i.e. `componentDidUpdate` *after* the state has been updated. In a pinch you can use the second argument to `setState`, a callback function, but this isn't recommended.

Code

```
addToCart = product => {
  const foundIndex = this.state.cartItems.findIndex(
    item => item._id === product._id
  );

  if (foundIndex !== -1) {
    this.setState(cartItems =>
      cartItems.map((item, i) =>
        i === foundIndex
          ? { ...item, count: item.count + 1 } // copy item and update count property
          : item
      )
    );
  } else {
    this.setState(cartItems => [...cartItems, { ...product, count: 1 }]);
  }
};

componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log(this.state.cartItems);
}
```